# OpenSSL ssl_accept() error 5

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl

I have scoured Stack Overflow and the internet, but I have been unable to locate an answer to why ssl_accept() keeps returning:

```
[DEBUG] SSL_accept() : Failed with return 0
[DEBUG]     SSL_get_error() returned : 5
[DEBUG]     Error string : error:00000005:lib(0):func(0):DH lib
[DEBUG]     WSAGetLastError() returned : 0
[DEBUG]     GetLastError() returned : 0
[DEBUG]     ERR_get_error() returned : 0
```

Edit:
Out of interest ssl_accept() returns 0, defined as (accordingly to the scant and unhelpful OpenSSL documentation):
"The TLS/SSL handshake was not successful but was shut down controlled and by the specifications of the TLS/SSL protocol. Call SSL_get_error() with the return value ret to find out the reason."

Below is the snippet of the server side, could I be barking up the wrong tree and this issue be caused by client code?

```
    client = accept( server, (sockaddr*) &clientsockaddrin, &len );

    SSL* ssl = SSL_new( ctx );

    SSL_set_fd( ssl, client );

    std::cout << "+--------------------------------------------------+"
              << std::endl;

    int r = SSL_accept( ssl );

    if ( r != 1 ) 
    {
        int err_SSL_get_error = SSL_get_error( ssl, r);
        int err_GetLastError = GetLastError();
        int err_WSAGetLastError = WSAGetLastError();
        int err_ERR_get_error = ERR_get_error();

        std::cout << "[DEBUG] SSL_accept() : Failed with return " 
                  << r << std::endl;
        std::cout << "[DEBUG]     SSL_get_error() returned : "
                  << err_SSL_get_error << std::endl;
        std::cout << "[DEBUG]     Error string : "
                  << ERR_error_string( err_SSL_get_error, NULL ) 
                  << std::endl;
        std::cout << "[DEBUG]     WSAGetLastError() returned : "
                  << err_WSAGetLastError << std::endl;
        std::cout << "[DEBUG]     GetLastError() returned : "
                  << err_GetLastError << std::endl;
        std::cout << "[DEBUG]     ERR_get_error() returned : "
                  << err_ERR_get_error << std::endl;
        std::cout << "+--------------------------------------------------+"
                  << std::endl;
        break;
    }
```

Appreciate your assistance as this is driving me mad :(

Comment: Wots '5'?  Access denied?

Comment: This is what I am not sure of, I can't find any definitive error codes list, without going through the OpenSSL source code I guess?

Comment: Did `client = accept(...)` fail? Its not clear if you are performing error checking. The Vista and above (or even XP SP 2) firewall will deny access by default unless you've placed a exception in the firewall rules.

Comment: [WSAGetLastError function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741580%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will help you with the error codes. Also, you *should not* delay the call to `WSAGetLastError` (or `GetLastError`). Call it immediately after `SSL_accept`. If `SSL_accept` succeeds, then simply ignore the return value.

Comment: Yeah, the only refs I found on the internet seemed to be because of failed connections on this one.

Comment: I will recheck my accept() verification statements, it's such as shame that the OpenSSL developers were lazy with the documentation.

Comment: @jww I removed the accept validation code in the code snippet...

Comment: @jww I tried moving WSAGetLastError() straight after ssl_accept with no success.

Comment: I think you should immediately call `GetLastError` immediately after `SSL_get_error`.

Comment: @dbasic I tried moving the call with no luck - see updates above :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [DEBUG]     Error string : error:00000005:lib(0):func(0):DH lib

The error happened during the Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange, e.g. where the peers tried to generate the keys for the connection. There might be several reasons for this, like invalid DH parameters given on the server side. With the your current code it is hard to see where the error actually is, but I guess is somewhere in setting up your ctx, so maybe should show the relevant parts of the code.

Comment: Oh, I don't actually setup a Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange, should I be doing this?

Comment: If you offer DH ciphers you need to setup DH keys.

Comment: could this be because I load all ciphers with ss_library_init ()?

Comment: No, but if you don't explicitly set a cipher list with SSL_(CTX)_set_cipher_list it will use the default set, which includes lots of ciphers and also DH ciphers.

Comment: Thank you, that has resolved it, now to fix the umpteen other issues ;) Don't you love OpenSSL :(

Comment: what was the solution? @PaulMorriss

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Diffie-Hellman library issue.
The reason you are getting the

> error:00000005:lib(0):func(0):DH lib

is that you passed in the `SSL_get_error()` error code to `ERR_error_string()` which you should not do.

`ERR_error_string()` is only used on error codes from `ERR_get_error()`.
See the help page for `SSL_get_error()` to know what the error means.

Comment: I believe you can use ERR_error_string() on ssl errors if you load the ssl error strings beforehand: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/SSL_load_error_strings.html