# SSL handshake fail on IOS only

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ssl, websocket

I'm developing an app using cordova (5.2.0).
On mac I'm using Xcode 6.4 to generate the .ipa

At some point I initialize a secure websocket connexion (certificates are not self signed, length is 2048) like this in js:

`socket_ip = new WebSocket(wss://perform.domain.com:8080, "image-processing-protocol");`

The connexion is working on Android and also from desktop browser (safari too).

However, from my Iphone(8.4) I got a :

> CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9807) which means "Invalid certificate chain"

On server side the message I got is:

> error:00000005:lib(0):func(0):DH

My sever configuration is:

- info.ssl_cert_filepath =
  "sslCertificates/myCert.cer";
- info.ssl_private_key_filepath ="sslCertificates/myCert";
- info.ssl_ca_filepath ="sslCertificates/GlobalSignRootCA.cer"
- info.ssl_cipher_list ="RC4-SHA:AES128-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5"

Looks like my issue is similat to [openssl-ssl-accept-error-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479376/openssl-ssl-accept-error-5) . I then tried to set up a cipher list without DH but I still got the error.
I am probably missing something to configure on my libsocket server.

As long as I'm using a commercial certificate and it's working with other devices I don't understand with the connexion with IOS failed.

Any Help would be much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Check your web site against [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and look for "incomplete chain". If you find it fix your server configuration. Some desktop browsers work around such problems with the server setup, most other ssl clients don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the checks as Steffen suggested. 
Solution was to set elliptic curve Diffie Hellman protocol up within libwebsocket.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an intermediate certificate from GlobalSignRootCA that you also have to add?