OpenSSL certificate incompatibility between versions 1.0.2 and 3.2.1
Recently, we have migrated to OpenSSL 3.2.1 from old 1.0.2 version. Earlier we're using the certificate with key size 2048 bits. Now, our application is not able to load those older certificates.
So, my question is, are older certificates in OpenSSL v1.0.2 are incompatible with newer OpenSSL version 3.2.1, even if certificate key size is 2048 bits?
I regenerated the certificates and it is working. But I wish older certificates should work.

There should be no problem due to key size. Can you provide more details about what happens when you attempt to load older certificates. What function do you call? Does it return an error? Are you using the OpenSSL "ERR" API (e.g. ERR_print_errors) to get error information - and if so what error does it report?

SSL_connect() is failing, SSL_get_error() returned error code 5. It looks to me, packaging of the certificate has changed in OpenSSL v3.*, can this affect loading of older certificate with newer openssl?

SSL_connect() doesn't load certificates directly so this is quite a confusing answer. It parses/verifies certificates sent from the server, and may send previously loaded certificates to the server if client auth is configured (not the default). So, can you clarify, what kind of certificates do you think are the problem: your server's certificates or some client side certificate for client auth? If SSL_get_error() returns 5 then that corresponds to SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL - which means OpenSSL attempted to make some low level syscall that failed, i.e. not directly a certificate problem.

@MattCaswell And given the question starts with "Recently, we have migrated to OpenSSL 3.2.1 from old 1.0.2 version...", that makes me wonder how that migration was done.  Was OpenSSL 3.2.1 installed over the top of a Centos 6 OpenSSL 1.0.2 installation, for example?

@AndrewHenle Our application uses openssl API's for handling secure connections. Earlier it was 1.0.2 and now migrated to 3.2.1 which caused major code changes.

@MattCaswell It looks certificate load is successful as it is showing issuer name, subject name etc. after calling X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert() API. X509_get_subject_name(), X509_get_issuer_name(), X509_NAME_oneline() are working correctly. Then SSL_connect() fails.

In this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479376/openssl-ssl-accept-error-5, some DH cipher list load problem is being discussed for this same error code 5 but during SSL_accept() call. Can this be my reason also? If so, how to fix that?

So it sounds like you are using some client side certificate for client auth. If SSL_get_error() returns 5 (i.e. SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL) then you should attempt to find out what the underlying error is. When this occurs, please check to see if OpenSSL has put any error messages on the error stack (e.g. by calling ERR_print_errors()). Also please check the value of errno. What platform are you running this on? (The diagnosis of a DH problem in that other issue is incorrect due to the reason given in the other answer. This other issue is unlikely to be relevant)

@MattCaswell We are running this on Windows 11. Will be debugging like what you've said and share the output next.

@MattCaswell Sorry for delay in responding. After some debugging, we found that OpenSSL 3.2.1 has removed many weak cipher suite which was available in 1.0.* version. After adding some stronger ciphers in server setup, now it is connecting. I'm still getting some warning, I'll post that some time later.

@MattCaswell After further analysis, we found that in earlier version of OpenSSL 1.0.2, all 100 ciphers (listed in the code) were sent to server. But with latest 3.2.1 openssl, only 14 of those listed ciphers are being sent to server. I wonder what can be the cause! Any clue why this new openssl sends only 14 ciphers? Are many old weaker ciphers are ignored? If so, from where can I check the list of ciphers being ignored by openssl 3.2.1?

Self answering this question.
After some debugging, we found that the ciphers which were being sent using OpenSSL 1.0.* and even using OpenSSL 3.1.* are not being sent now when using OpenSSL 3.2.1 version.
Then I came across a new API SSL_CTX_set_ciphersuites() in addition to older API SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(). OpenSSL 3.2.1 mandates that for any TLSv1.3 related or mixed cipher, you need to use SSL_CTX_set_ciphersuites() as well as SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(). When used this approach, now all intended ciphers are being exchanged.
Additionally, SSL_CTX_set_security_level() API can be used to set security level to 0 (zero) to make it backward compatible. Set secirity level to 1 in which case RSA, DSA and DH keys shorter than 1024 bits and ECC keys shorter than 160 bits are prohibited. Set security level to 2 in which case RSA, DSA and DH keys shorter than 2048 bits and ECC keys shorter than 224 bits are prohibited. More details can be found on openssl documentation.
